# Draw a graph with tikz-pgf whose coordinates are not all numerical

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to represent the following points in a `pgf` graph:

```
(48th 2019,3350.3333)
(49th 2019,4587.4286)
(50th 2019,3569.7143)
(51th 2019,5209.4286)
(52th 2019,4232.2857)
(53th 2019,5540)
(1st 2020,4039.5714)
(2nd 2020,3660.1429)
(3rd 2020,4181.4286)
(4th 2020,2859.2857)
(5th 2020,3559)
(6th 2020,4845.8571)
(7th 2020,3804.2857)
(8th 2020,3353.5714)
(9th 2020,4067.5714)
(10th 2020,2867)
(11th 2020,1967.4286)
(12th 2020,1234.5)
```

The `x` axis is the week of the year, the `y` axis is a real number. If the abscissa values were numeric, I could write something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.85]
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=Week,ymin=1500,ymax=5500,colormap/blackwhite,
    cycle list name=black white,
    smooth]
    \addplot coordinates{(1,4739) (2,4324) (3,2685) (4,4960) (5,3065) (6,2527) (7,3006) (8,3463) (9,3269) (10,3271) (11,4358) (12,4038) (13,3616) (14,2503)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I don't know how to modify this code to get what i want. Could you help me please?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120041/replacing-axis-labels-with-text-in-tikz see if the bottom answer helps, using xtick labels.

Comment: @PaulA: Hi, thank you! It helps